# Перенос данных с Drupal на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, drupal

Есть сайт на Drupal, доступы все есть, как из него можно вытянуть содержимое страницы и перенести на WordPress с подключением библиотек?

Comment: а jquery тут причем? у WP есть плагин (и не один) для этого.

Comment: ну в drupal есть папка, и в нем файлы, с подключением библиотек, каким плагином можно перенести данные на страницу WordPress?

Comment: я не использую ни drupal, не wordpress. я просто поискал в гугле и нашел несколько плагинов.

Comment: пример можете скинуть ?

Comment: пример чего? запроса в гугл?

Comment: названия плагина, т.к. именно под свою цель я пока что не нашел годного

Comment: вот первый попавшийся https://wordpress.org/plugins/fg-drupal-to-wp/

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal+to+wordpress+plugin

Answer (score 0):

Весь кастом с библиотеками нужно подключать вручную в WordPress через functions.php. Тоесть скопировать файлменеджером распакованые библиотеки с Drupal и перенести в WordPress.

С более-мение стабльных плагинов по переносу контента есть FG Drupal to WordPress Premium.

Моя рекомендация, переносить все вручную(Контент типы,  записи БД, Медиа, Пользыватели), тоесть распаковывать локально БД двух сайтом и через запросы делать копии контента.Личная практика оклоло десятка переносов показала, что меньше времени нужно на написание  собстенного переноса нежели исправлять после автоматического переноса с использыванием сторонних средств, особенно если на Drupal стоят разные "интерестные" модули.